# How to reset Keras data generator in R?

Tags: r, keras, reset, prediction

When we are dealing with data generator ( for training or testing purposes) in Keras, there are cases when we want to reset the generator.

The following code is an example of test_generator in R using Keras:

```r
# define the test generator:
test_generator<- flow_images_from_directory(path_to_folder,image_data_generator_object,target_size = c(h_w),class_mode="binary",batch_size =10,shuffle = "FALSE")

#evaluate the model:
my_model%>% evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps = 100)

# Now I want to reset my test_generator before using it for prediction.
# what should be the code?

#predictions
my_model%>%predict_generator(test_generator, steps = 100)
```

What I want is to reset the data generator between thge evaluation and prediction step ( because the order is not maintained.

In **Python**, this is what I usually do:

```py
test_generator.reset()
```

I cannot find the **equivalent** of the **reset** function in **R (keras)** . Any help?

Comment: the only thig I do now that works is to use two different generators for evaluation and test( to avoid reset). but it would be nice to be able to reset the same generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always run `generator$reset()`.

What I usually do is to create a function that automatically starts a generator. Then I can just run it like this:

```
 my_generator <- function() {
    flow_images_from_data(X_train, Y_train, datagen, batch_size = 32)
  }

  # train using generator
  x <- model %>% fit_generator(my_generator(),
                               steps_per_epoch = 32, 
                               epochs = 2)
```

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what I have been looking for.